# MATCH...AGAINST... does not return expected results

Tags: mysql, sql, match-against

I have this record in a table:

> TAS1J0413031AB32-E14-0SKODAOctavia97-F

But when I try to search like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM `cross_lists`
WHERE match (`cross_value`)
          against ("*1J0413031AB*" in boolean mode)
```

I didn't get any results.

But when I try with `OX143D` in `OX143DAUDIA3/VWGolf-4/Bora1.9TDI`  it works OK, `1J0513425` in `107649=HP=1J0513425VWGolfIVRear`  all is ok.

What am I doing wrong? How do I get the results I need?

How can I easily find a string that occurs anywhere?

Comment: How many records do you have in your database that contain that string?

Comment: @Pekka but identical string appear's only in ~5 records...